# How to make the HEAD pointing to origin/master

Tags: git, git-fetch

I mistakely applied the branch on top of my master branch and committed the change.
But now I want to make my HEAD point to the origin/master.

I have tried the below command :

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

But my log shows the HEAD is pointed to master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, change-branch, etc.

[image]

How can I make my HEAD point only to (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) not to change-ID like below?

**Expected log :**

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot : it so happens that, at the moment, your two local branches `change-494895-1` and `494895-1` point to the very same commit as `master` and `origin/master`.

They won't interfere in any way with your work on `master` or on the rest of the repo. For example : next time you make a commit on `master`, or pull an update from `origin/master`, `master` will move forward, and these two branches won't.

---

If you need to do something with those two branches :

- if one of them is useless, just delete it : `git branch -d <branch_name>`
- if you need to work on one of those branches : `git checkout <brnach_name>; #some work; git commit`
- etc ...

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard e2ac6469
git push -f
```

The first command will point HEAD to `master`.

The 2nd command will move HEAD, along with `master`, to point to the commit you want (you can see the commit ID in your screenshot, `e2ac6469` . You don't need to include all the digits)

The 3rd command will move the remote `origin/master` to point to the same commit as `master`, namely `e2ac6469`.

If you still want the commit that `master` used to point to, it is still on branch `change-494895-1`.  You can get to it with `git checkout change-494895-1`.

Comment: Actually the expected log has the same commit Id, which I have now updated in the question. But applying your suggestion with the updated committed id results same. Could you please have look at the updated question and provide a suggestion?